# How to adjust Geometric Brownian Motion to be monotone?

Tags: data, sde

I want to use stochastic process to model subscriber's mobile data consumption as time going in a month. So I think about Geometric Brownian Motion.

However, people's cumulative data consumption will never decrease. Thus, how can I adjust the formulation of Geometric Brownian Motion to make it monotone? Or is there any other stochastic process more suitable?

Comment: Instead of modelling your total consumption to follow a GBM, you could e.g. model the instantaneous rate of data usage as a GBM $X_t$ then your total consumption is $Y_t = \int_0^t X_u \mathrm{d}u$. However, you should question if the a GBM is a reasonable model for the instantaneous rate of consumption - e.g. should it have a drift but no intra-day/week/month seasonality, ...?

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Could you please explain how to compute Y_t? There is a  Wiener process within X_t, how to deal with it in the time intergral?

Answer (score 1):

You could model this as a Lévy-process. The class of [subordinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinator_(mathematics)) can be used to model processes that never decrease. If the increments are Gamma-distributed then this is a gamma subordinator. Depending on what you want to do with the model the class of Lévy processes is studied in detail. You can look for more details [here](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/LevyProcesses.pdf). Compound Poisson processes fall in this class as well but I think they don't come that natural in your case.