# Time integral of geometric brownian motion

Tags: sde, asian-option

Suppose $S_t$ is a geometric brownian motion. Then how to understand its time integral, i.e., $Y_t=\int_0^{t}S_udu$?

Is $Y_t$ still a stochastic process?

How to compute the expectation of $Y_t$?

How to compute the expectation of $\left[a-Y_t\right]^+$?

Here $[x]^+=\max\{x,0\}$.

Comment: Search for "Asian option" in the site's search bar, there is plenty of Q&A addressing these issues.

Comment: Daneel Olivaw is right. That being said, yes $Y_t$ is a stochastic process. The expectation operator being linear computing the expectation should be straightforward (just swap integral and expectation operators). For the non-linear payout you won't have a closed form result because the distribution of $Y_t$ is not analytically tractable, there are other options though (PDE, Monte Carlo).

Comment: The two are right. If you look at my answer to your [original question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36637/how-to-adjust-geometric-brownian-motion-to-be-monotone) (I suppose the two are connected) then you I really think you need the Asian option for Levy processes.

Comment: Thnks. Could  you elabrate more why Asian option for Levy processes?